# To close db and cannot create commands from unopened database error

Tags: xamarin.android, android-sqlite

```
    string dppath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "user.db3");
    db = new SQLiteConnection(dppath);
    string DELETEPASSCODE_DETAIL = "DELETE FROM Table1;";
    db.Execute(DELETEPASSCODE_DETAIL);
    db.Close();
```

Hello. When the program executes the above code and reaches the below code, I get this error: `cannot create commands from unopened database`

```
     try
            {
                string dpPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "user.db3");`
                if (dpPath.IndexOf("user.db3") < 0)
                {
                    CreateDB();
                    CreateTable();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (db == null)
                    {
                        db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
                    }
                    var tableExist = db.GetTableInfo("Table1");
……
```

The error occurs on this `db.GetTableInfo("Table1");`

Comment: Have you try to test the try part? I can not reproduce this issue, could you provide more details for me?

Comment: Hello and thank you. I connect to the database to remove the table from the database and then close this connection (db.Close()) and connect to the database again. Here, I imagine db is null, why not null? And then the error happens here, that is, on `db.GetTableInfo("Table1") ` and I see `cannot create commands from unopened database. ` db.Close() doesn't close the database completely?

Comment: Ohhh, I think i know what cause this issue. You deleted the table not the database. It would not be null.

Comment: I delete the rows of the table and then use db.close(). I do not delete the table. Why is db not null despite db.close()?
Should we say db=null instead of db.close()? Or not to use db.close() and db=null at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some mistakes for the first check of the code. Now, I reproduced this issue.

[image]

The db can not be null, delete the If statement.

**Change:**

```
 if (db == null)
            {
                db = new SQLiteConnection(_databasePath);
            }                
            var tableExist = db.GetTableInfo("Info");
            var table_Info = db.Table<Info>().ToList();
```

**To:**

```
    db = new SQLiteConnection(_databasePath);
            var tableExist = db.GetTableInfo("Info");
            var table_Info = db.Table<Info>().ToList();
```

`db.Table<Info>().ToList()` could also be used to get the table information.

Comment: Hello. Thank you. when the program is started, db is null, It is true? And we need to use SQLiteConnection.
If SQLiteConnection is established, how should we test that it is established and And avoid re-establishing it?

Comment: My next question: In your examples, db can not be null, then why give this error: cannot create commands from unopened database? I'm really confused.

Comment: @user2111639 The db defined in class and initialized. It could not be null and the the code could not run into the if statement.  So you got the error when the db did not create the connection with the code `db = new SQLiteConnection(_databasePath);` .

Comment: Hello. With `db.Close()` and `db.Dispose()`, db will not be null but with `db = null`, db will be null. https://learn.microsoft.com about `SqliteConnection.Close Method` states that _Closes the connection to the database. Open transactions are rolled back_.

Comment: yes, we could use the `db =null` after `db.close()`. I test it and it works.

Comment: Can we never close db? Can we imagine that if the application is closed, db will be closed and this connection will be lost?

Comment: I never close the db. When we close the app, the db would close and the connection would close as well. But the database you created exists in location you saved.